# Public SMTP Server - Send email from localhost WAMP PHP

Tags: php, smtp, localhost, wamp

I'm having problems sending an email from PHP in my localhost, I use WAMP and PHPMailer. I don't want to install a SMTP server in the localhost so my question is: is there any public SMTP server that I can use?, I just want to change the SMTP value in the php.ini and no more, is that too much to ask?

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm correct, you can use google's smtp server if you have a registered account. Here are the details: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=166852

Comment: Public SMTP servers have gone the way of the dodo, t-rexes, and the credibility of politicians - extinct.

Answer (score 0):

Any openrelay SMTP server you use will probably make your mail go to the spam folder of any decent email provider.

If you have any mail account, like gmail, you can configure PHPMailer to send email from that account trough SMTP.

Comment: if the email is sent then that enough for me, I don't care if the email goes to the spam. I don't want to mess around configuring PHPMailer  with gmail. What about my question??